# In Angular, how to ignore a file using .htaccess

Tags: angular, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using Angular 9.x. I need to ignore a specific file in the root directory. For example:

```
/root
   - index.html
   - ignorefile.json
```

I tried adding a rewrite rule to .htaccess with no success.

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ignorefile\.json$ [NC] # this does not work
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

How can I ignore a specific file when compiling the app?

Comment: Angular is a frontend framework, i.e. it runs in the browser. `.htaccess` files are used on some web servers.
Where are the files? Why are they part of your angular project? Do you need them during the build?

Comment: @joel the .htaccess file is autogenerated by the Angular CLI. I don't need the ignored file to be part of the project, I just need it ignored by the rewrite rules.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know the angular CLI could generate an .htaccess file. how? 

But you are deploying on a webserver that uses the .htaccess files, right? Can't you just exclude the ignorefile.json from your app's distribution?

Comment: If that’s a physically existing file, then the two RewriteConds that check on the request filename with the `!-f` and `!-d` flags should prevent the following rule from doing any rewrite already. Not sure where the actual issue is supposed to be here?

Comment: What do you mean by ignore file? If you type `http://example.com/ignorefile.json`, which result do you expect? a 404? The home page? The file itself?

Comment: @David the file itself, i.e. foo.com will load the Angular app, but foo.com/ignorefile.json will show the json data.

Comment: Maybe try without the first slash : `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^ignorefile\.json$ [NC]`. Otherwise, add a rewrite rule like for index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**INFO**

Angular does not generate & handle server-side redirections.

To handle the navigation in Angular from one view to the next, you use the Angular router. The router enables navigation by interpreting a browser URL as an instruction to change the view.

When the router navigates to a new component view, it updates the browser's location and history with a URL for that view. As this is a strictly local URL the browser won't send this URL to the server and will not reload the page.

If you are using the (Angular 9 default) PathLocationStrategy for modern browsers, they support history.pushState, a technique that changes a browser's location and history without triggering a server page request. The router can compose a "natural" URL that is indistinguishable from one that would otherwise require a page load.

In this case, the server needs to redirect all traffic to index.html so Angular can take over to handle path on UI. For this, you have to append a .htaccess file to your production server in order to make routing work.

**ANSWER**

If you are trying to serve ignorefile.json along with your angular app, it is quite possible. You should update your angular.json file.

```
   "assets": [
     ...
     {
       "glob": "ignorefile.json",
       "input": "src/",
       "output": "/"
     },
     ...
   ]
```

foo.com will load the Angular app, but foo.com/ignorefile.json will show the JSON data.

Check this answer; https://stackoverflow.com/a/61972932/2827820

Answer (score 0):

use the same rule as for index.html, and I would suggest to add `RewriteBase /`.

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond ^ignorefile\.json$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

if it doesn't work - make it more strict

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond ^ignorefile\.json$ - [END]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```