# Angular - How to configure a passthrough for a folder of external assets?

Tags: angular, url-routing

**Background:**
A project I am working on needs to access photos from a system we've recently updated from AngularJs to Angular 16.  Originally, we served these photos from a virtual directory, like `https://myawesomesite/photos/{photonamehere}.jpg`  Not only did photos in that path appear in the actual application, we were able to send those URLs to applications that draw off the data our app governs and basically centralize all the photos related to the app's domain.

**Problem:**
When we changed to Angular 16 this stopped working.  When one would attempt to directly navigate to a photo URL like above, one would simply be bounced to our application's frame with the `NG04002` routing error.

Because these photos live outside of our SPA, we need to ensure that routes patterned like `./photos/*.*` are excluded from Angular's routing system in our app.

**Research:**
I've looked through a number of StackOverflow questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61902703/ignore-a-path-in-the-root-routermodule), and these sorts of questions inevitably refer back to the official Angular documentation on [Asset Configuration](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#asset-config).  What I believe I need to do is, in angular.json, add the following block under the architect/build/options/assets array:

```
{
  glob: "photos/*",
  input: "./photos/",
  output: "./photos/"
}
```

...However, the documentation is very unclear about what precisely someone needs to do to ignore a part of a route, which means `https://myawesomesite/photos/*.*`.  Further, the way the documentation is worded simply doesn't make sense to me; I'm aware that the `glob` property is a special, Angular specific path syntax relative to `input`, and that `output` is a path relative to whatever the output directory for the project is, it's not clear how this works together and how to write a well-formed `asset` array entry.  Worse, Googling for examples of this doesn't really turn up any results, or at least I'm not searching on the correct terms to get results on how to do what I'm trying to do.

While I'd happily ask for the Angular team to make that particular documentation more readable for someone trying to quickly solve problems, all of this leads to my question...

**Question:**
In what way can I get Angular to ignore a folder of static assets that hangs off of the root URL by way of being a virtual folder?  Is what I've settled on from my research correct or close to correct, or is there a different and better way to do this, without dumping everything into some kind of an assets that lives within the Angular project?

Comment: You may want to show your Routes array...  I'm able to just do something like  <a href="{{baseURL}}/WebApi/ServeJpg?id={{thisImage.id}}"><img src="{{baseURL}}/WebApi/ServeJpg?id={{thisImage.id}}" height="40px" /></a>  And it works just fine.

Comment: To understand you correctly, are you saying that this is something that needs to be set up in my `app-routing.ts` file?  Is `angular.json` the wrong place to be trying to set this up?

Comment: there could be a route setup that's causing that error...  or you are trying to use a routerLink for this... you're missing that bit too... you should include more code in your post.  (related to the router error you are receiving)

Comment: I am not attempting to use a router link - when I attempt to directly navigate to a photo URL like `https://myawesomesite/photos/{somephotoname}.jpg`, I should see a photo.  What I actually see is my application, which has the NG04002 console error.  Is that clearer?

Comment: Additionally, I'm not 100% sure that I can code my way out of this problem.  While it's plausible that changing my `app-routing.ts` file could be a way to resolve this, all the material I've found in my research keeps pointing me back to Angular's asset system.  Please re-read my question and make an effort to fully understand what I'm asking.

Comment: seems like the server is redirecting all routes to your SPA.   (Which I guess is fine if your SPA knows where those assets are...)

Comment: the options (glob, input, output) you are setting only affect the build... I don't think that has any affect on routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the resolution to my problem was external to any of the code I wrote.

The short version of what was going on, was that there was a configuration issue in how the virtual /photos directory had been set up, compared to how it used to be - my shop has some ongoing infrastructure changes we're making at the moment.

I'm not sure of the exact order of operations or the mechanisms in play, but it seems like an external resource that exists with an absolute URL based in your project, but that appears in your virtual directory (https://myawesomesite/photos/myradphoto.jpg) will appear if it's present.

If it's not present, then either the browser or Angular itself appears to attempt to employ its routing systems to try to do a navigation.  If however /photos/myradphoto.jpg isn't a valid route - and, it probably won't be - then you get the technically correct NG04002 error.

So, if your photos don't show up and you get a broken SPA, two key debugging steps are:

1. Make sure your photo is actually where you expect it to be
2. Make sure your external resource virtual directory is correctly configured.

Comment: An additional note here: unless you use hash routing (as I do...) it's common to setup the server to redirect all paths to the SPA... i.e. serve up index.html. (otherwise if you refresh the browser or bookmark a page you'll receive a 404)  If you have assets, you need to exclude that folder/path. That was part of my confusion here... if you use hash routing in angular you only need the root domain name to go to the SPA... all other paths will "fall-through" naturally... (the server doesn't serve up index.html, so it uses it's own routing rules which may or may not be folder-based)